# Using nested for loops to create a data frame in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, arguments

I was looking to find a way to use two for loops to create a specific data frame in R. I got started on a function but was having some difficulty with it. The first for loop would loop through the names of a list of data frames and the second for loop would loop through the columns of each data frame and give back the mean. The output would then give back a data frame with each row containing the means of the columns for one of the data frames. Here's some dummy data:

```
first<- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Hi","Hi","Hi")), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
               z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
second<- data.frame(b = factor(c("Med", "Med", "Med", "Med")),y = c(3, 2, 6, 5),
                z = c(1, 11, 4, 3))

third<- list(first,second)
fourth<- c("first","second")
names(third)<- c(fourth)
fifth<- c("y","z")
```

Here's the function I was working on:

```
testr<- function(arg1,arg2){
  a<- list()
  for(i in 1:length(arg1)){
   b<- (third[[arg1[i]]])
    for(j in 1:length(arg2)){
      c<- mean(b[[arg2[[j]]]])
      a[[j]]<-c
    }
  }
  df<- do.call("cbind",a)
  df<-as.data.frame(df)
  df$name<- arg1
  return(df)
}
```

My goal would be this result:

```
testr(fourth,fifth)

    V1   V2  name
1 7.25 1.25 first
2    4 4.75 second
```

But instead I get this:

```
testr(fourth,fifth)

 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name", value = c("first", "second" : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ b, data = rbind(first, second), mean)` gives something which resembles your desired output. But perhaps I don't understand the full complexity of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have many such data frames as `first` and `second` and a list of such data frames as follows, you can use `dplyr` to get the desired result as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
l <- list(first, second)
df <- do.call(rbind, l)
df %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Output is:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

       b     y     z
  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1     Hi  7.25  1.25
2    Med  4.00  4.75
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice... let's just avoid for loops all together. It looks like you just want the mean of the two columns and the name of the data.frame.

Pick up some skills with `dplyr` or `data.table` that make this type of summarization trivial.

```
library(dplyr)
third %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "name") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(
    V1 = mean(y), 
    V2 = mean(z))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#
#     name    V1    V2
#    (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  first  7.25  1.25
# 2 second  4.00  4.75


library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(third)
dt[,list(V1 = mean(y),V2 = mean(z)),by = b]
#      b   V1   V2
# 1:  Hi 7.25 1.25
# 2: Med 4.00 4.75

# or as David points out.
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = b]
#      b    y    z
# 1:  Hi 7.25 1.25
# 2: Med 4.00 4.75
```

Comment: You can do `dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = b]`